# How do I align these inline bullet points?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, enumitem, inline

I have the code

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\makeatletter
% This command ignores the optional argument for itemize and enumerate lists
\newcommand{\inlineitem}[1][]{%
\ifnum\enit@type=\tw@
    {\descriptionlabel{#1}}
  \hspace{\labelsep}%
\else
  \ifnum\enit@type=\z@
       \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi
    \quad\@itemlabel\hspace{\labelsep}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
    \begin {itemize}
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item Substrate (\textbf {S}) \inlineitem Enzyme (\textbf {E})
    \item Complex (\textbf {SE}) \inlineitem Product (\textbf {P})
    \end {itemize}
\end{document}
```

And I want like them to be in line with each other. I.e., the substrate bullet point is inline with the complex one (which it is), but also the Enzyme bullet point to be inline with the Product bullet point which they're currently not.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where is `\inlineitem` coming from?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, provide small but complete document, which we can compile. where is defined `\inlineitem`?. if i understand you correctly, you looking something similar to table ...

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the package I used. I'll edit it now

Comment: @Zarko: Sorry, I did not see that you proposed the tabular approach already

Comment: @Gragbow: `enumitem` does not provide `\inlineitem`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ah does it not? I have loads of packages you see, because I'm making a poster. I'll try to find the package I used

Comment: @ChristianHupfer,  i'm glad that you elaborate idea. to me the op question was quite unclear, so i didn't try to wrote an answer ... (+1 for yours)

Comment: @Zarko Sorry that's my bad, always forget that usual formatting doesn't really work in poster templates

Comment: Whatever you mean by “poster template”, please post a complete example that illustrates it (in which the solutions posted below do not work).

Comment: Apparently the Michaelis-Menten Complex is too complex for the poster template ;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two ways, one with a tabular and a special `B` type (B like in Bullet) and one with the `tasks` environment (which is to be preferred)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{B}[1]{@{}>{\textbullet\quad\raggedright}p{#1}@{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{B{5cm}}}
  Substrate (\textbf {S}) &  Enzyme (\textbf {E}) \tabularnewline
 Complex  (\textbf{SE}) &  Product (\textbf {P})
\end{tabular}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
\task Substrate (\textbf {S}) \task Enzyme (\textbf {E})
\task Complex (\textbf {SE}) \task Product (\textbf {P})
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**A version with a tabular only, removing the indent by \noindent**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcolumntype{B}[1]{@{}>{\textbullet\quad\raggedright}p{#1}@{}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{B{5cm}}}
  Substrate (\textbf {S}) &  Enzyme (\textbf {E}) \tabularnewline[1ex]
 Complex  (\textbf{SE}) &  Product (\textbf {P})
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `tasks` way is to be preferred here, in my point of view

Comment: See the issue is that I'm using this in a poster template, and 'tasks' isn't really compatible. It ends up producing this https://gyazo.com/1e688f0549c00a98aa8ac41e50cd0b2f

Comment: @Gragbow That's why it's always better to post a complete (but minimal) example with your question, matching the actual document classes you use. It saves everyone's time. Your example in the question (at least as of [the current version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/413826/4)) does not start with `\documentclass`, for instance, so it won't even compile.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yeah but I thought my poster template would be too large to post as it contains loads

Comment: @Gragbow: **Don't** use templates -- they are too restrictive and most times just bad, written by people that glue things from 100000000000 internet sources together

Comment: @Gragbow: If you think your code is too long to post here, post it to [Pastebin](//pastebin.org) and provide the links here.

Answer (score 7):

The `[inline]`  option of `enumitem` isn't designed for lists aligned in columns, but for horizontals lists with a constant  horizontal spacing between items, like the  `inparaenum` and `inparaitem` environments from `paralist`.

For lists aligned in columns, you can use the `tasks` package, but also `shortlst`, which can be found on CTAN, but isn't part of  TeX Live or MiKTeX, for licensing reasons.

Here I defined a `tabitemize` package with an optional argument, the number of columns of the alignment (`3` by default). Note that when an item content is wider than a single column, it uses the current column and the following one:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{shortlst}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][3]{%
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\labelitemi}%
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\parindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\begin{shortitemize}}%
{\end{shortitemize}}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabitemize}[2]
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item Substrate (\textbf {S})
    \item Enzyme (\textbf {E})
    \item Complex (\textbf {SE})
    \item Product (\textbf {P})
\end{tabitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added: Procedure to install the `shortlst` package* for every user:

First you need to have a `texmf-local` directory root for local additions. It already exists for TeX Live and MacTeX, but not for MiKTeX.
For MiKTeX, you have to open `MiKTeX Settings (Admin)`, `Roots` tab and click on the `Add…` button to add a new TeX directory root. You may give it the name you want. Its content has to be organised according to the TeX Directory Structure (`TDS`).

Next, download the CTAN  package. It contains only two files: `shortlst.dtx` and `shortlst.pdf` (the documentation). Put the .pdf file in `texmf-local\doc\latex\shortlst\`.

Then you have to create `shortlst.sty`. For this, you compile `shortlst.dtx`, which produces a series of files, among which `shortlst.pdf` (the documentation again) and the most important `shortlst.ins`. Compile `shortlst.ins`. Another series of files, among which the precious `shortlst.sty`, that you put in `texmflocal\latex\shortlst\`.

Last step: delete all files, except those you've placed in `texmf-local` and `refresh the FNDB`, with MiKTeX Settings (Admin) again (`General` tab).

Comment: This produces an error saying the shortlist.sty file is not found?

Comment: You have to download it from CTAN and install it in your *local*. As I said it's not in the official distributions, but is available from CTAN texmf tree. You can get it from [this link](https://ctan.org/pkg/shortlst).

Comment: When I try and install manually I keep getting this error,https://gyazo.com/c012f93d915d17aaea44c264066e894f When i try and open my settings

Comment: Did you  run the compiler on `shortlst.dtx` to obtain `shortlst.sty, then install the latter  in `texmf-local/tex/latex/shortlst` and refresh the FNDB, since you use MiKTEX? Also do you a `local texmf root `, duly declared?

Comment: Mate, Im literally new to Latex. I'll explain what I've done, I've downloaded that file. Ive then extracted the files into my working folder. I've then opened Miktex settings as admin, gone to roots and clicked on my working file. But it says https://gyazo.com/3478c1c52fc882dc32eb1be6ef58dfb3 and I dont know what this means

Comment: It says  that your directory is not valid, because not considered as respecting the  TeX Directory Structure (acronym TDS). Anyway, I think it should not be put in a personal directory if you want any user to have access to this package. I've added in my answer detailed explanations on how to proceed. In particular you have to obtain first `shortlst.sty`. Let me know if it's not clear enough.